# call functions of viewModel from user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have `View1`, `ViewModel1` (which is DataSource for `View1`) and `UserControl` (`TextBlockComboBoxUC`).
`View1` contains `TextBlockComboBoxUC` in XAML like this :

```
<vwKomp:TextBlockComboBoxUC
    ComboBoxItemSource="{Binding Path=ZoznamStatov, Mode=OneWay}"
    ComboBoxSelectedValue="{Binding Path=TrvalaAdresa.Stat, Mode=TwoWay}">
</vwKomp:TextBlockComboBoxUC>
```

`TextBlockComboBoxUC` contains `TextBlock` and `ComboBox`.

How can I call the method from `ViewModel1` when `ComboBox`'s `SelectionChanged` event is raised?

I suppose somehow via delegates, but I have no information about `UserControl` in `ViewModel1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the [MVVM Light library](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), I think you can set up a trigger for that event to call the command:

```
<vwKomp:TextBlockComboBoxUC
    ComboBoxItemSource="{Binding Path=ZoznamStatov, Mode=OneWay}"
    ComboBoxSelectedValue="{Binding Path=TrvalaAdresa.Stat, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
             <cmd:EventToCommand
                 Command="{Binding YourSelectionChangedCommandHandler}"
                 PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</vwKomp:TextBlockComboBoxUC>
```

Where:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

Source: http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/